# Python OpenCV avoid Video Source -> Capture source dialog

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, video, webcam

So I'm trying to create a simple program on python 2.7.5 where a window would
show live video feed for a user chosen time.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time


def Func_VideoCapture(Float_Time = 10):
    Float_WantedTime = time.time() + Float_Time
    Float_CurentTime = time.time()

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while Float_CurentTime <= Float_WantedTime:
        #get current time
        Float_CurentTime = time.time()

        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Float_Time = float(raw_input(">>> "))
    Func_VideoCapture(Float_Time)
```

But when i run it a dialog asking for my camera pops-up(Video Source -> Capture source).
How can i hide it from the user?
P.S. I also tried to run the...

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

...in the main function but the result is the same:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

def Func_VideoCapture(cap, Float_Time = 10):
    Float_WantedTime = time.time() + Float_Time
    Float_CurentTime = time.time()

while Float_CurentTime <= Float_WantedTime:
    Float_CurentTime = time.time()

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    Float_Time = float(raw_input(">>> "))
    Func_VideoCapture(cap, Float_Time)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

P.S.#2 I'm on Windows but i don't have to necessarily use this version of python or OpenCV

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time


def Func_VideoCapture(Float_Time = 10):
    Float_WantedTime = time.time() + Float_Time
    Float_CurentTime = time.time()

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)



    while Float_CurentTime<=Float_WantedTime:
        #get current time
        Float_CurentTime = time.time()

        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Float_Time = float(raw_input(">>> "))
    Func_VideoCapture(Float_Time)
```